# Prove $a=(12345)$ and $b=(21345 )$ are NOT conjugate in $A_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

I had to find two 5-cycles in $A_5$ that are not conjugate.
I believe I found two, namely $a=(12345)$ and $b=(21345)$.

It wasn't part of the exercise, but I'd like to prove that they are not conjugate.  But I'm not sure where to start.  I think we have to start with that they are conjugate in $S_5$, so there exists a $g \in S_5$ such that $gag^{-1}=b$. And then prove all the $g's$ for which that is true are $\notin A_5$?

Someone stated this as a duplicate, but I don't think it is, because they don't really ask for/ give the algebraic proof that I'm looking for.

Comment: Two cycles with the same length are always conjugate.

Comment: @Bernard  They are not conjugate, because there are 4!=24 5-cycles in $A_5$, the order of $A_5$ is 60, and 24 does not divide 60.